# How .gitignore file is processed?

Tags: git, gitignore

I am developing a system to mimic the gitignore functionality. I will add certain rules ( gitignore pattern format) to a file and the file will be input to a script (perl) file, when there is any commit the script file parses the rules and if any rule matched then it will send an email.

For this I need to know basically where to find the gitignore source code and how its been implemented in git so that I can have similar implementation in my proj.

Comment: The source code for `git` is right here: https://github.com/git/git

Comment: Maybe you could make use of `git check-ignore` command? See: http://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore.html

Comment: Or man gitignore (https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitignore.html) gives you quite detailed specification.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the code for gitignore processing is around somewhere here: https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/builtin/check-ignore.c#L68